# Can I add a softer CSS style to a cell back colour?

Tags: css

Question: Can I add a softer CSS style to a cell back colour?

Issue: Gridview highlights in Red/Yellow/Green if something needs doing. As you can imagine this looks a bit garish at the moment.

What I want to do is add a soft edge around each cell. So I have two schools of thought but don't know enough about CSS to find the answer (I could be searching for the wrong keyword)

1) Add a soft edge around the cell colour
2) Create a 'soft padding' for each gridline that takes the edge of the colours like a mask.

The code!

CSS code I use at the moment to change the cell colour:

```
e.Row.Cells(iLoopColumn).BackColor = Color.Green
```

I have found colour gradient at [www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) but how do I merge the two, if that is the right route.

```
background: #f0b7a1; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0b7a1 0%, #8c3310 50%, #752201 51%, #bf6e4e 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f0b7a1), color-stop(50%,#8c3310), color-stop(51%,#752201), color-stop(100%,#bf6e4e)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f0b7a1 0%,#8c3310 50%,#752201 51%,#bf6e4e 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f0b7a1 0%,#8c3310 50%,#752201 51%,#bf6e4e 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f0b7a1 0%,#8c3310 50%,#752201 51%,#bf6e4e 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0b7a1 0%,#8c3310 50%,#752201 51%,#bf6e4e 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f0b7a1', endColorstr='#bf6e4e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

Comment: Can I use the .style?  e.Row.Cells(iLoopColumn).Style

Comment: I guess one potential approach would be to use a box-shadow with the inset keyword specified. If you make the colour of the shadow the same colour as the background (assuming a single, solid colour for the background) you get an effect that has soft edges. Something like this: `box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(255,255,255,1.0);` For more: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Comment: Thanks @enhzflep but how do I get that to work with e.Rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that gives entire rows in a table a soft-edge effect. The key points are

- Give the targeted rows a class so you can target them with the css
- Apply the `disply: block` style to force colouring the row (it also
  removes default padding between cells)
- Use 2 different classes - one to apply the soft-edge effect, the
  other to set the colour of the row.

[image]

Note: only tested with Google Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.softEdge
{
    display: block;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
}
.red{ background-color: #F00;}
.green{ background-color: #0F0;}
.blue{ background-color: #00F;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr class='softEdge red'><td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td><td>cell 3</td></tr>
        <tr class='softEdge green'><td>cell 4</td><td>cell 5</td><td>cell 6</td></tr>
        <tr class='softEdge blue'><td>cell 7</td><td>cell 8</td><td>cell 9</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```